# iOS create a background service to send IP updates to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am relatively new to iOS development.

I have a requirement wherein it is important for us to notify our server about a client's current IP address. The reason behind this is because our solution needs to know the current IP address of the registered device.

Now ideally we would want to create a service that can run in background (indefinitely), poll the ip Address of the device every 10 seconds, and if it sees that the ip has changed, then call a web service notifying the server about the same. I have the folowing questions based on my limited knowledge:

1. Apple gives us limited choices for apps that are allowed for running
   background threads (VoIP, background download, music playing,
   location updates etc.). Unfortunately my use case is not an exact
   fit for any of these. Can I still go ahead and somehow accomplish
   this?
2. I have read that iOScan close any background thread if it needs
   resources. Although my process is not resource intensive, should I
   be worried?
3. The background mode will only start once my app has been MANUALLY
   started. What I mean to say is that suppose I am able to run this in
   background, but for this to happen the user has to once start the
   app manually after restarting the device. Is there a way to start a
   service/thread on restart? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trust IOS to handle this in the BG for you the way you describe it, because there is no good way to have a task run in the BG indefinitely, you might get away with using location services and trigger your IP uploads when a device moves but that will not resolve the situation when the device is stationary and changes IP although that might be a corner case but will surely happen as the device moves from tower to tower on 3/4G networks or between different WIFI networks.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was looking at location services as an option as well but it has too many loopholes (plus Apple might not approve it). I am looking at Background Fetch API as a potential option. There are a couple of delegate methods that seem to fire when an app is in background. Maybe they can help.